# DLL load failed error while using python imagebot

Tags: python-2.7, dll, scrapy

**cmd.exe view.* I use pypi imagebot which based on python scrapy to download images[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYKBp.jpg) and on Windows 10 32 bit get ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.* 
**How to fix DLL load error?** Systems variables image attached. Python and scrapy versions updated.

C:\Users\Vartotojas>imagebot crawl http://seorinkodara.weebly.com
                                  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
        "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
        exec code in run_globals
      File "C:\Python27\Scripts\imagebot.exe__main__.py", line 5, in 
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\imagebot\main.py", line 2, in 
        from scrapy.crawler import Crawler, CrawlerProcess
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy__init__.py", line 34, in 
        from scrapy.spiders import Spider
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders__init__.py", line 10, in 
        from scrapy.http import Request
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http__init__.py", line 11, in 
        from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 9, in 
        import lxml.html
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\lxml-3.3.6-py2.7-win32.egg\lxml\html__init__.py", line 42, in 
        from lxml import etree
    ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.